# Initializing 'jQuery UI Sortable List' in pre-defined order

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list made as sortable using jQuery UI.  The first list item is “Item 1”, second is ‘Item 2” like that.  My requirement is the list items must be initialized  based on the order stored in the array “arrValuesForOrder“. How do we initialize it so?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.13/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () 
    {

        var arrValuesForOrder = ["3", "1", "4", "2"];

        $("#myUnorderedList").sortable({
                                    axis:'y',
                                    handle: '.handle',
                                    update: function () 
                                            {
                                                var order = $('#myUnorderedList').sortable('serialize');
                                                alert(order);
                                            }
        });
    }); 
</script>

<style>

#myUnorderedList li img.handle 
{
margin-right: 20px;
cursor: move;
}

#myUnorderedList li 
{
display: block;
margin-bottom: 3px;
height:30px;
background-color: #efefef;
}

</style>


</head>

<body>

<div>


<ul id="myUnorderedList"> 

  <li id="listItem_1"> 
    <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="move"  class="handle" /> 
    <strong>Item 1</strong> 
  </li> 

  <li id="listItem_2"> 
    <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="move" class="handle" /> 
    <strong>Item 2</strong> 
  </li> 

  <li id="listItem_3"> 
    <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="move"  class="handle" /> 
    <strong>Item 3</strong> 
 </li> 

  <li id="listItem_4"> 
    <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="move" class="handle" /> 
    <strong>Item 4</strong> 
  </li> 

</ul> 


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the sortable plugin comes with an option to set the initial order of the elements. I think it expects the elements to be initially rendered in the correct order (which makes sense in my opinion - why don't you do that ?)

Anyway, here's a piece of code that will sort the elements prior to initializing the sortable plugin:

```
var arrValuesForOrder = ["3", "1", "4", "2"];

var $ul = $("#myUnorderedList"),
    $items = $("#myUnorderedList").children();

// loop backwards so you can just prepend elements in the list
// instead of trying to place them at a specific position
for (var i = arrValuesForOrder[arrValuesForOrder.length - 1]; i >= 0; i--) {
    // index is zero-based to you have to remove one from the values in your array
    $ul.prepend( $items.get(arrValuesForOrder[i] - 1));
}

$("#myUnorderedList").sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    handle: '.handle',
    update: function() {
        var order = $('#myUnorderedList').sortable('serialize');
        alert(order);
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/beAwC/)**

Comment: Suppose the array value is coming from database, what is the best approach to display it? Essentially I am trying to store the list position in database and retain it when the user comes back. I am looking for a solution applicable for list and <div>

Comment: My solution is applicable to anything. You can do `$('#myelement').children()` instead of `$('#myelement li')` to not be bound to LI elements.

Comment: This will re-order the items only after the code has loaded and won't initally show the order you want.

Comment: How is your page constructed ? Any server-side language like asp.net ? If you cannot sort the elements server-side, you can maybe hide the list initially, sort it and show it only when it is sorted.

Comment: You question does not make sense. Server-side you don't sort <div> but the data that is populated. I guess you are using repeaters (or else) with databinding. Sort your data before the binding then. But this is a totally different problem than the one in your question though and you may post another question if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to store the pre-order in JS? If it is hardcoded HTML, why don't you change the HTML? And if you use a scripting language, why don't you use that to pre-order?

I'm not sure if `sortable` has triggers to move items, but either way it would not be a good idea to do that after initialization of your script, because the items will load as 1,2,3,4 and then on document.ready rearrange..

Comment: If it is coming from a database, `order` the query to get the results in the order you want...

Comment: It must be a list for `sortable` to work. Why would you make it a div? What you have now is fine..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way using 3 sortable and ordering them by the id of the html element

[image]